# VBA Delete Excel column and header if all cells in column (except header) are empty?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have some vba code that populates an excel table with specific texts.  I'm hoping to add a function to the code that deletes a column (and the header) if that column is empty (no text strings present).  I have searched for some codes but none have been able to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try by yourself and when you encounter difficulties, come back with the specific problem and the code. You already said that there are answers on the web.

Comment: Hint: worksheetfunction.CountA(activesheet.columns(x)) will be zero if column x is empty

Comment: I'm still trying to work out whether the [access] tag has been used because your really are having some access control issue that is stopping you from updating the spreadsheet, or whether you meant to use [ms-access] (but nothing in the question suggests MS Access is involved in any way).

Comment: YowE3K, I should have used MS Access.  My code uses an MS Access database to populate the excel spreadsheet I mention.

Answer (score 0):

Below simple function will check, if given column is empty. Optional argument let you set, if empty column should include headers.

```
Function IsColumnEmpty(ByVal rngColumn As Range, Optional bIncludeHeaders As Boolean = True) As Boolean
    IsColumnEmpty = False
    If bIncludeHeaders = True Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngColumn) = 1 Then
            IsColumnEmpty = True
        End If
    Else
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngColumn) = 0 Then
            IsColumnEmpty = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

To delete an empty column you can use it as below:

```
If IsColumnEmpty(Sheets(1).Column(1)) = true then
    Sheets(1).Column(1).Delete
End If
```